# How to add tags(not HTML) on click of "Enter" button and then save it in string format?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to add tags in a textbox. I searched for the same but most of them showed using github or something. One which I could use was this:

```js
$('#textarea input').on('keyup', function(e) {
  var key = e.which;
  if (key == 188) {
    $('<button/>').text($(this).val().slice(0, -1)).insertBefore($(this));
    $(this).val('').focus();
  };
});

$('#textarea').on('click', 'button', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).remove();
  return false;
})
```

```css
#textarea {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

#textarea input {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 6px;
}

#textarea input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#textarea button {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 4px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#textarea button:after {
  content: "\d7";
  color: red;
  margin-left: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="textarea"><input type="text" /></div>
```

it did get the thing which I type in tags as i wanted but I am not able to get the value back in string format. please help.

Comment: @mplungjan its the comma key.. i'll set it to 13 so that it works on Enter press

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at .map and .get()

```js
var tagsFromAngular = "testtag,abcd"

function tagify(input) {
  $input = $(input), val = $.trim($input.val());
  if (val !== "") {
    $.each(val.split(","), function(_, tag) {
      tag = $.trim(tag);
      if (tag) $('<button/>').text(tag).insertBefore($input);
    });
  }
  $input.val('').focus();
}

$(function() {
  var $inp = $('#textarea input');
  $inp.val(tagsFromAngular);
  tagify($inp);


  $inp.on('keyup', function(e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if (key == 13) {
      tagify(this);
    };
  });

  $('#textarea').on('click', 'button', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).remove();
    return false;
  })
  $("#show").on("click", function() {
    console.log(
      $("#textarea>button").map(function() {
        return $(this).text()
      }).get()
    );
  });
});
```

```css
#textarea {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

#textarea input {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 6px;
}

#textarea input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#textarea button {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 4px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#textarea button:after {
  content: "\d7";
  color: red;
  margin-left: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="textarea"><input type="text" value="" /></div>
<button id="show" type="button">Show tags</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much . It does works. I am actually entering the data and saving it back to MsSql via the following method :

 var tempTagData = $("#textarea>button").map(function () { return $(this).text() }).get();
            var tagData;
            for (var i = 0; i < tempTagData.length; i++)
            {
                if (tagData == null || tagData == undefined || tagData == "")
                    tagData = tempTagData[i];
                else
                    tagData = tagData+","+tempTagData[i];
            }


This saves the data in string format with comma separator

Comment: Hence on page load I get bac kthe data in string format with values as comma separated. How can I display the same data as tags back in the same div ?

Comment: See update - If the input is pre-filled, it will be converted to tags

Comment: i'm getting the data from angularjs and binding it to the textbox:

 $scope.tagsdata = response.data.tags;       

<div id="textarea"><input type="text" value="{{tagsdata}}" /></div>


but it binds the whole of the string as one tag

Comment: Also if the data is null then one empty tag appears in the div.

Comment: Now the code can handle empty input.
What does {{tagsdata}} contain? I split on comma and trim. If it is not a string containing commas, then the code needs to be changed. The code to bind the string has to run before the code I have to create tags of course

Comment: tagsdata contains "testtag,abcd"

Comment: So my code will work if it runs after the angular fills the input

Comment: Whn I try to send the data "testtag,abcd"  in the function val value shows ""

Comment: I cannot help you with the angular - the javascript above works if the input field has a comma delimited **string** before the script runs

Comment: See my update, which is NOT using angular. It is now back to you. The code works. I fake the angular thing using `$inp.val(tagsFromAngular);`